# react-three-fiber multiple meshes lose models except for last one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have been developing an application in React using `react-three-fiber` to visually display data. I am trying to create different models by passing data denoting their properties as props into components. My problem occurs here as while inside each component I am able to add a simple shape (e.g. cube) and get it to display properly, when I declare a model inside each component to be used it only seems to be picked up for the last component created;

Top-level component canvas simplified

```js
return (
    <div> 
        <Canvas> 
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Items items={this.state.data}/>
            </Suspense>
        </Canvas>
    </div>
)
```

Middle-level component

```js
// count is to identify the position in the loop so that the meshes do not overlap 

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ITEM from './ITEM';

class Items extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
            <ITEM key={i} item={item} count={i}/>
        ));
    }
}
```

Bottom-level component

```js
// I have been using the drei GLTF loader to get the model

import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {useFrame} from 'react-three-fiber';
import {useGLTF} from 'drei';

const Model = ({modelPath}) => {
    const gltf = useGLTF(modelPath, true)
    return <primitive object={gltf.scene} dispose={null}/>
};

const ITEM = ({item, count}) => {

    const modelPath = '/model/scene.gltf';

    const mesh = useRef(null);
    useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));
    return (
        <mesh castShadow position={[1, 1, 1]} ref={mesh}>
            <Model modelPath={modelPath}/>
        </mesh>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [gltfjsx](https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx) to convert your GLTF models into react components, then you can use props to edit certain properties about them.

Comment: this is the solution. in threejs you can't have one and the same object in multiple places. the model boils down to a THREE.Scene, which is then mounted two times. GLTFJSX on the other hand creates an immutable scene graph and the model can now be re-used. to solve this without GLTFJSX would need cloning, which is added cpu, memory and performance drop.